# Calculate Timeslots between Timestamps in Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

let's say i have an php array like that:

```
Array ( [0] => 2017-08-25 06:27:00 [1] => 2017-08-25 07:38:00 [2] => 2017-08-25 08:34:00 [3] => 2017-08-25 09:57:00 [4] => 2017-08-25 11:08:00 [5] => 2017-08-25 12:37:00 [6] => 2017-08-25 14:12:00 [7] => 2017-08-25 15:21:00 [8] => 2017-08-25 16:59:00 [9] => 2017-08-25 18:08:00 [10] => 2017-08-25 19:05:00 [11] => 2017-08-25 20:03:00 [12] => 2017-08-25 21:04:00 [13] => 2017-08-25 21:59:00 [14] => 2017-08-25 23:02:00 )
```

And want to calculate the time in minutes between each timestamp in the array.

Output should be 
Array ( [0] => 69 [1] => 56 [2] .... )

I have no Idea how to solve that for example with an foreach.

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: See also: [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/676824/250259)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a quick go, just looping through and checking if there's a next value, then subtracting it, and dividing by 60 to get minutes:

```
$dates = ['2017-08-25 06:27:00', '2017-08-25 07:38:00', '2017-08-25 08:34:00', '2017-08-25 09:57:00'];

$values = [];

foreach ($dates as $index => $date) {
    $date = strtotime($date);
    if (!empty($dates[$index+1])) {
        $nextDate = strtotime($dates[$index+1]);
        $values[] = ($nextDate-$date) / 60;
    }
}

var_dump($values);
```

Comment: Great!  $index+1 is the key ;-) haven't known that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Even though the answer has already been accepted, I thought I'd give my input nonetheless as I feel there are other options that are more robust and clear/easier to understand.

## The Object-Oriented Approach

PHP has a collection of native objects specifically designed to handle date calculations, namely `DateTime` and `DateInterval`. making use of those objects will make the code easier to read and understand, which in turn means the code is easier to bug and more maintainable.

```
$dateArr = ['2017-08-25 06:27:00', '2017-08-25 07:38:00', '2017-08-25 08:34:00'];

$previousDate = '';
foreach($dateArr as $dateStr) {
    $curDate = new DateTime($dateStr);
    if(!empty($previousDate)) {
        $diff = $previousDate->diff($curDate);
        echo $diff->format('%i min').PHP_EOL;
    }

    $previousDate = $curDate;
}
```

This loop will output the following:

```
11 min
56 min
```

Of course, if you want to use this value for calculations, you'll need to do some extra manipulation to turn it into a numeric value type.

```
$min = $diff->format('%i');

if(is_numeric($min)) {
    $min = (int) $min;
    echo $min.' ('.gettype($min).')'.PHP_EOL;
}
else {
    echo 'Oops, something went wrong :('.PHP_EOL; // good place to throw an exception, this echo is only for demo purposes
}
```

Outputs:

```
11 (integer)
56 (integer)
```

---

Using the `DateTime` object will also allow you to catch badly formatted dates much more easily as it throws an exception instead of failing silently.

```
try {
    $wrongDate = new DateTime('foobar');
    echo $wrongDate->format('Y-m-d h:i:d').PHP_EOL;
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage().PHP_EOL;  // the exception is caught
}

try {
    $wrongToTime = strtotime('foobar');
    echo $wrongToTome.PHP_EOL; // no exception si thrown and 
                               // an undefined variable notice is thrown
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage().PHP_EOL;
}
```

---

Try it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aaeb6b9336661b202bd2c0c9967663046aa47164)!

---

#### Related Documentation

- [`DateTime` class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)
- [`DateInterval` class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)
- [`DateInterval::format()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)
- [`strotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 0):

Convert the strings into timestamps (seconds) using [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) or [strptime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php), then simply subtract.

Comment: Thanks, so far its clear. But if i loop through the array for example that way foreach ($a as & $v) {
 $diff=date_diff(strtotime($v),strtotime($v+1));
}  How is it possible to get the value of the next array value?